# Веб сокеты PHP Сервер удаляет сам себя

Tags: php, сокет, websocket

Веб сокеты PHP
Есть код который я с копипастила на ютюбе, он работает в одном проекте, но когда я использую этот-же код в другом проекте то он удаляет сам себя. (OS)
Я не смогла понять в чем проблема, но удаление происходит если в коде есть socket_listen()(
Помогите пожалуйста

```
<?
$Port = "101010";
$adress = "127.0.0.1";
//require_once("socket/socketServ.php");

function ConsolLog($message) {
echo $message.date(" h:i:s")."\n";
}

ConsolLog("Сервер запущен");

$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
socket_set_option($sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1);
socket_bind($sock, $adress, $Port);

ConsolLog("Сокет сервера настроен");

socket_listen($sock, true);//Если отключить прослушку то начинает работать нормально

$ClientSocketArray = array($socket);

ConsolLog("Прослушка сокета работает");
?>
```

Я специально убрала цикл что-бы облегчить код, потому-что проблема не в цикле а в запуске прослушки сокета.

У меня сервер не "падает", у меня удаляется файл сервера при завершение его выполнения в не зависимости от цикла.
Не думайте пожалуйста что я совсем тупая и не понимаю как работают сокеты, циклы и PHP в целом, и я специально отметила зачем убрала рабочий цикл, но повторю еще раз и более развернуто: "что-бы вы на него не отвлекались, так как проблема появляется только если в коде есть функция прослушки сокета"

Comment: другой проект на том же хостинге с той же конфигурацией?

Comment: Это все на OpenServer

Comment: Очень может быть проверкой хостинга на соответствие правилам у автоматического удаления файлов по признакам. Смотрите их документацию и пишите на поддержку. Запустил на ПК с OpenServer - никаких удалений не наблюдалось.

Comment: Здравствуйте, это может не решит проблему, но порт не может иметь значения 101010, максимум 65535